# cPickle dump files

Tags: python, sql, pickle

cPickle (python library) can dump files to store python pickle objects. What would I need to do to create a dump file that could be loaded by a MySQL database from a cPickle dump file? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm fairly sure that cPickle dump files are fairly different from MySQL dump files and can't be directly loaded because of incompatibility issues. Is there a tool/script that I would need to use/create to convert between the two?

Or would I need to write a python script to load the objects from the cPickle dump file and then execute SQL queries in the script based on the fields from the objects to migrate information between the 2 databases?

Comment: Yes, you would need to write a conversion script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a conversion script.  However, the good news is MySQL can import CSV files, and Python has a built in [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).  So you can actually do this in only a few lines of code.  On the MySQL end, just use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data/stuff.csv' INTO TABLE YOUR_TABLE_HERE
```